# How do I make a worker from the cluster module run a specific function or script in nodejs

Tags: node.js

So I am trying to experiment and learn the cluster module in Nodejs and I want the worker to run a specific function but when you fork a worker it will just run the whole entire script that the master used

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using clustering, but rather you should just start a child_process or WorkerThread that you can then send messages to and it can have code in it to process those messages.  Clustering is for making more versions of your main process.   WorkerThreads or child_processes are for independent threads/processes that can respond to messages you send them and do independent work for you.

Comment: Well, I tired those but I need a thread that is in or has the same data and the main, I am trying to find a type of threading that is kind of like python's multithreading module where the threads are in the same data space or have the same data as the main thread. Clustering is really the only thing that is similar in my opinion. Also I don't like how the messages in worker threads and child_processing work

Comment: Reason I want to use this whole cluster and multithreading thing is because I was to transfer one of my terminal games from python to javascript for fun and I only want to do it on nodejs. I have the game on my replit and I can show you the link and see the code if you can understand python, [link](https://replit.com/@Legendthecoder/List-game-engine-test-3?v=1)

Comment: Nodes does not have threads that share main data. You can pass data to threads via messaging. If game is mostly just processing events and not heavy calculations, you may not need threads in nodejs.

Comment: Ok well is there atleast a way to have clusters on run specific functions?

Comment: As I already said, that is not what clusters are for.  You would do that with a child process or workerthread which each can run whatever custom code you give them at startup. And you can then pass them messages to tell them what work to do.

Comment: welp I am going to try to work around it, child processing and worker threads didn't really do a good job and messaging kinda sucks in my opinion

Comment: So, just to be clear here, clusters are separate processes and don't share memory either.  So, not sure why you're trying to hard to make that work for you when that's not at all what it is designed to do.

Comment: oh, Ok now I understand sorry, I just want to find a type of multithreading in nodejs just like python's multithreading module

Comment: Nodejs does not contain a threading model like Pythons.  Nodejs threads runs in their own variable space (don't directly share variables) and are event driven.  Neither of those is like Python threads.  You can use shared memory between two threads, but it's a pretty raw way of sharing, essentially just a raw buffer that you have to construct variables out of and make sure you provide your own concurrency protection.  So, there is no direct mapping between the two.  The best implementation in nodejs would be a rethink into the nodejs event driven architecture.

Comment: Wait dude actually I was experimenting with messaging in child process and it works amazingly well! so yeah thanks alot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.